# tcpdump http request/responce Wireshark

Tags: linux, wireshark

> sudo tcpdump -i enp2s0 -n dst port 8080 -w test_tcpdump.dump

I'm using this command on a linux to simply dump everything that goes through port 8080..

But why can I only see the request from HTTP and not the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dst port 8080` - this captures traffic with **destination** port 8080 only.
The response packets have **soruce** port 8080, but the destination port will be some random port selected by the client.

Change the filter to `port 8080` and you will see packets coming from/to port 8080 (i.e. both directions)